# Why is Mikan never shown nude?

Tags: to-love-ru

Bit of a NSFW question.

In the anime, as far as I know, Mikan was never shown nude. Why is that? The manga of *To Love Ru* has no problem showing her nude so I'm a bit curious as to why the anime didn't. I thought at first that it was probably due to her being under the age of consent and yet the anime has no problem showing characters like Yami and Celine, who have similar child-like appearances, nude.

Comment: Anime is under different regulations than manga. It's also why it's a lot easier to find underage characters drinking in manga than it is in anime. Not sure if that is the answer, though (hence this being a comment).

Comment: After quick research... there seems to be no definitive answer, only speculation (aka. "it's complex"). The closest thing of Mikan being nude is in *Motto To Love Ru* episode 1 while in the spring bath. Japanese fans have theorized that it's due to Yami and Celine being not "human", while Mikan is. However, there's another anime where a 10-year old girl is shown naked (*Haganai* episode 8). Also, there's nothing preventing *To Love Ru Darkness* OVA from showing Mikan nude, but indeed, OVA is not broadcasted on the TV (no links because... well... all are NSFW in general)

Comment: @AkiTanaka _Haganai_ had to be censored for TV, so it could still be some kind of TV regulation. The censoring was removed for the DVD / Blu-Ray release. (Can't give references, unfortunately; my only reference is that I saw a censored scene from the first season of _Haganai_ in a fansub ripped from the TV broadcast, and then later bought the Blu-Rays and saw it uncensored.)